# What should be the special power of my fifth equestrian race?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process, super-powers

In my equestrian world, the 5 equestrian races lived happily,

These are: **earth-horses**, **pegasus with wings**, **unicorns with magic**, **zebras of potions** *(and black magic)*, and in the end **the donkeys of the empire.**

The world was a healthy combination of magic and technology, but one day the black magic war broke out and the world was destroyed (something like a nuclear apocalypse).

Now each race had something that matched the battle between them.

**The ground horses had both super-strength and super-agility and good reflexes.**

**Pegasus, could fly through the sky and attack from above.**

**The unicorns could use magic (nothing extraordinary but also had its limit)**

**Zebras could create magical potions and communicate with the world of spirits.**

***But in the end they were the Donkeys of the empire, I do not know what to give them ...***

*What would be a good power for your race:* ***super strength? Immunity to magic? Super ears?***

*I need ideas as they are a major race in history ...*

And yes is for **that** Show...just shsssssss...don´t say anything

Comment: The ability to think for themselves. On a more serious note, however, this question is very opinion based, and as such not a good fit for this site. The reason this is, is because we may each come up with significantly different answers, and yet we would have no objective way to determine which may be best. What you're really doing is having us make up reasons for this race to be significant, which is not done here. You're the author. You can come up with a list of abilities and ask if they make sense, but we don't create your universe for you.

Comment: Alright, I will delete this post by the end of the day.

Comment: Before you delete, I'm going to reccomend giving donkeys a heightened resistance to magic. This is mostly because donkeys, from what I've seen, are noted for their intelligence and their stubbornness. As a side note, it might be interesting to think about where mules would fit in this story. Given that in *that* show some one actually says 'be cool or be mule', that could shed some light on the world's inter-species relations...

Comment: You should join the Worldbuilding chat and run your ideas by some people! We also have a question sandbox in WB Meta that you can use to test people's reactions to your questions. Last but not least, don't give up simply because the way you framed your question now is considered out of scope.

Comment: @Lot-Of-Malarkey Thanks for the feed back, I really like the Idea, and I didn´t remember that line from the show, thanks a lot I can expand upon that.

Comment: Here are the links from the resources @AndreiROM mentioned: [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) can be found on [Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/) and the main chat is called the [Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor).

Comment: Also: every edit of yours will automatically send the post to a special reopen review queue where people vote whether the new revision fits the guidelines of the site. Only after a week without any activity a question becomes closed, which means that it will not automatically be sent into the review queue, though it could still be reopened.

Comment: Also

Thanks @AndreiROM 7 I´m still new to the site, and I need to lear a lot from it, I will take upon you advice and make sure I use the Sandbox next time, and maybe you are right, I need more people willing to give me feed back.

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold, but Donkey could be associated with kicking strength per the film [Gus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gus_(1976_film))] (although, technically, Gus is a mule;)  Power of seduction is a possibility (see Book 10 of [The Golden Ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Ass)).  I'd actually say Asses are more associated with magical transformation, per Apuleius and Shakespeare in the character of [Bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Bottom), but Shakespeare's Bottom was also an object of the lust of Titania, the Faerie Queen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an appropriate power can be found for your Donkeys by examining what are the **aspects** of the other equestrian races **beyond** simply their abilities.

Indeed to me each of the five races embodies one out of five essential metaphysical characteristics or elements.

- The ground-horses represent **the body**: Their abilities do not evoke the supernatural, they simply have mastery over their physical form, capable of taking physical prowess to incredible/super-equestrian (see what I did there?) heights. Ground-horses tend to be determined, pragmatic and steadfast.
- The pegasi represent **the spirit**: they do not achieve flight by merely flapping their wings (they'd have to be prohibitively big for that to be possible), instead their wings are simply conduits for their spirit which allow their to escape from their earthly tethers. Pegasi are typically independent, eccentric free-thinkers.
- Unicorns represent **the mind**: through the application of sheer mental will they are capable of producing magic of the psychokinetic and psionic varieties. They are usually reasonable, strategic and visionary.
- The Zebra represent **the heart**: highly intuitive and empathic, zebras are talented at sensing the subtle motions and shades at play in the world and in objects/people. They use this prowess to produce powerful potions from ingrediants any other type of equestrian would overlook or be unable to know how to combine. In addition, this instinctive knowledge makes it possible for them to see beyond the viel and contact the dead. Zebras practice ritual magic and are compassionate, resourceful and wise.
- Finally there are the Donkeys: To figure out what they represent one must simply look at what's missing. In this case it is **the soul**. Now a lot people will say the soul is the same as the spirit but in many (most) theologies/metaphysical systems/mythologies, this is not the case in the slightest. Typically the spirit is seen as a supernatural energy field permeating the body (sometimes called life force/Chi/Prana) while the soul is thought to be the core/essense of being. Donkeys represent the latter and as souls are obviously very static and durable objects this is where the stereotype that Donkeys are very stubborn comes from. In fact empire Donkeys are **resilient**, not stubborn. Resistant to magic, to disease, to physical blows and in a way **to death**, it's rather difficult to kill an Empire Donkey as they keep getting back up even after having been dealt otherwise fatal injuries, though of course they'll eventually succumb (they are after all not immortal).

Comment: MIND= BLOW!!! 

This is perfect!!!

(Should I still delete thos post or...)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it was a world of magic and technology and have two races devoted to magic (unicorn and zebra). What if the Donkeys were good with technology? They aren't necessarily the strongest in any sort of way but they compensate for this with what would amount to future technology.

I'm thinking along the lines of Daleks in Doctor Who where they're almost powerless on their own but have enhanced themselves through technology to the point they can hold their own to the stronger races.

Comment: I really like the Idea, but that is more an archivement of the race, more than a power from the race...so...